# Formatting Axis Labels in MS-Access Chart

Tags: ms-access

Is there a way to make the fields on the left fit better?  I have expanded the chart & adjusted a few properties but nothing seems to work
[image]

Comment: Is this Access "Modern Charts" utility?

Comment: Yes this is modern charts

Comment: I find access is the red headed step child of Microsoft Office.  Access doesn't get as many features and updates as the other office programs.  One work around is to export the table or query to Excel then use Excel's charting functions.  Also it would help to provide the data in the question.